# Firebase - Rules for using realtime database without firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my application, I have my own authentication system which uses **JWT**. I want access to the realtime database, however I don't want to make use of Firebase Authentication

I tried setting "write: true, read: true" in the database, however this resulted in getting a insecure database rules message.

What rules/methods could I implement to combat this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any JWT you want with security rules.  You must use Firebase Authentication in some way.  If you already have a user management system, you could possible use [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to mint a token on your backend for Firebase Auth to sign into your app that represents one of the users in your existing auth system.